# Change Webform hidden values via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-webform

I've created a Drupal site in which I'm including an external PHP file and an external JS.
They both seems to work.

Then I added a webform which contains some hidden fields.
One of the functions of the JS has to change these hidden fields value.
On page source code I saw these fields are named "submitted[**comp_name**]" where **comp_name** is the name of the specific field, as defined in webform.

The JS function has 2 input formal parameters, one is **comp_name** and the other is **id**. The purspose is to set the **id** value to the **comp_name** field.

I tried:

```
document.getElementByName("submitted["+comp_name+"]").value = id;
```

and also

```
$("#submitted["+#comp_name#+"]").val(id);
```

but when I try to send the webform, the hidden values remains the same as default.

What I am doing wrong?
Is it possible to change webform hidden value via javascript??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `submitted["+comp_name+"]` is the `name` of your element, but in javascript we don't have `document.getElementByName`, but you can do it like:

```
document.querySelector("input[name='submitted["+comp_name+"]']").value = id;
```

or using jQuery do:

```
$("input[name='submitted["+comp_name+"]']").val(id);
```

but if `submitted["+comp_name+"]` is the `id` do this:

```
document.getElementById("submitted["+comp_name+"]").value = id;
```

or using jQuery:

```
$("#submitted["+comp_name+"]").val(id);
```

Comment: The querySelector worked for me! :-)
Thank you very much Mehran!

Answer (score 0):

If `submitted[comp_name]` is the `id=""` of the field, then this should work:

```
$('#submitted[' + comp_name + ']').val(id);
```

Without the `#` as you used in `#comp_name#`.

However, if `submitted[comp_name]` is the `name=""` of the field, and the field is an `<input>` element, then do this instead:

```
$('input[name=submitted[' + comp_name + ']]').val(id);
```